# Required Files Not Found, Ghost Files And Folders In My Project

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hello I am having a rather peculiar issue with an angular theme i downloaded, i have the following file in my project:

**theme-core.js**

```
(function e(t,n,r){function s(o,u){if(!n[o]){if(!t[o]){var a=typeof require=="function"&&require;if(!u&&a)return a(o,!0);if(i)return i(o,!0);var f=new Error("Cannot find module '"+o+"'");throw f.code="MODULE_NOT_FOUND",f}var l=n[o]={exports:{}};t[o][0].call(l.exports,function(e){var n=t[o][1][e];return s(n?n:e)},l,l.exports,e,t,n,r)}return n[o].exports}var i=typeof require=="function"&&require;for(var o=0;o<r.length;o++)s(r[o]);return s})({"./src/js/themes/angular/theme-core.js":[function(require,module,exports){
// Curriculum
require('../html/_curriculum');

// Scrolling behaviour
require('../html/_scroll');

// Quiz timer
require('../html/_countdown');

// Earnings chart
require('../html/_flotchart-earnings');

// Angular App
require('./angular/app.js');
require('./angular/config.router.js');
require('./angular/main.js');

// Library Directives
require('../../../../lib/essential/js/angular/main');
require('../../../../lib/layout/js/angular/main');
require('../../../../lib/sidebar/js/angular/main');
require('../../../../lib/maps/js/angular/_google-maps');
require('../../../../lib/media/js/angular/main');
require('../../../../lib/material/js/angular/main');

// Custom Directives
require('./angular/directives/navbar-transition-scroll');
require('./angular/directives/countdown');
require('./angular/directives/curriculum');
require('./angular/directives/flotchart-earnings');
```

Now this is my folder structure inside my **public** folder:

[image: Folder Structure]

As you can clearly see from above, there are no angular, html, lib/essential folders in my project, yet somehow those files appear to be required in my **theme-core.js** file

Now when i decided to take out those required files the application doesn't load, i get errors in my browser console, the application works offline too.

I am confused by this since this is a new theme i downloaded and i am trying to use it but i cannot seem to find those files it is loading.

Comment: Judging by the way some of those paths traverse the directory tree I'd say the files are outside your public folder. `Requiredd` files don't have to be publicly accessible. Try folding the paths carefully around the file system

Comment: That's just it, i didn't write the above file, it came with the theme i downloaded and i use laravel framework so all my js,css,image,font files are in my public folder, i personally copied those folders from the theme folder and put them inside the public folder of my project, so there are no theme related files outside the public folder just my framework stuff.

Comment: And the weird thing is that even though those folders aren't in my project the application still runs without any errors.